# Nlohmann JSON парсинг массивов

Tags: c++, json, парсер

Начал изучать библиотеку Nlohmann JSON и столкнулся с такой проблемой как парсинг массивов json.

В инете инфы найти не могу, документацию тоже вроде как всю прочитал(скорее всего я просто слепой).

Может быть, кто нибудь, подскажет неопытному, как вытащить например из такого файла информацию по датам?

```
{
    "group": "пми-21бо",
    "progress": {
        "1": {
            "2019/01/01": {"plus": true, "attendance": true, "test": 3.5},
            "2019/07/01": {"attendance": true}
        },
        "2": {
            "2019/01/01": {"attendance": true, "test": 1.5},
            "2019/07/01": {"plus": true, "attendance": true}
        }
    }
}
```

Например из этой строчки мне нужно узнать значение `"plus"` , `"attendance"`, `"test"`. Как это делается?

Вытащить значение `"group"` я могу, делаю это вот так

```
cout << json["group"].get<std::string>() << endl;
```

А с массивами никак не могу разобраться.
Буду рад помощи.

Comment: в указанном json нет массивов

Comment: `json["progress"]["1"]["2019/01/02"]["plus"].get(bool)` не работает?

Comment: Возможно работает, но если я например не буду знать сколько записей дат?

Comment: тогда надо получить итератор, и перебрать их видимо? `json["progress"]["1"].begin()` вы как документацию-то читали?

Comment: Можно реализовать точно так же как в этом задании https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1116306/nlohmann-json-итераторы/1116394#1116394 Только в место "test" поставь то что требуется найти